# Checking which checkboxes have been checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

So I have a html for with 9 checkboxes. I am trying to use JQuery to check when they have been checked/toggled. This is my current code.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
                alert("Checked");

            });
        });
</script>
```

And here is my html setup:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1"/>
        <label for="1"><span>1</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2"/>
        <label for="2"><span>2</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3"/>
        <label for="3"><span>3</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4"/>
        <label for="4"><span>4</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="5"/>
        <label for="5"><span>5</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="6"/>
        <label for="6"><span>6</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="7" name="7"/>
        <label for="7"><span>7</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="8" name="8"/>
        <label for="8"><span>8</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="9" name="9"/>
        <label for="9"><span>9</span></label>
</form>
```

The above code has no alert output. What is wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fa3RW/ seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VYLgE/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        var x = (this.checked) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

or

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VYLgE/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        if(this.checked){
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

do it like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
             if($(this).prop("checked"))
                alert("Checked");

        });
    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/S5RTv/) is a demo fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             alert("Checked");
        }     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attribute` selector and the `:checked` selector to obtain the inputs.  Then iterate through the checked inputs using `.each()`

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(i,e){
    alert(e.id);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/YyP4E/